# Accessing Administrative Share Using Listener Name

Tags: sql-server, replication, availability-groups

Can a SQL Server AG listener name be used to access an administrative share
i.e  `\\DB-listener\c$\Somefolder`?

I can RDP using the listener name but can't use the listener name to access the `$` shares (as mentioned above).

Comment: What happens when you try the path? If you get an error message, please edit the question and add it there. Why would you like to use listener and admin share anyway?

Comment: The Listener name always refers to the active node of the AG, being able to use the Listener name would save a step or 2 in having to go the folders on the active node.  This was possible for FCI but I guess not with AG's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the listener name to access administrative shares on the cluster nodes.  When accessing a cluster network name (which is what a listener is), shares are scoped to clustered shared folders only.

Please see [Deploying a two-node clustered file server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/failover-clustering/deploy-two-node-clustered-file-server#shared-folders-in-a-failover-cluster) for reference.